# RabbitMQ - Delayed message exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, messagebroker

Currently, we have 2 systems that are communicating directly.

Service A continuously (but not in periodical manner) sends messages to service B. The Message is in simple Key/Value format. Key is an integer number and Value is current local date and time.

Service B, in order to decide whether to process the request, has this logic to examine the last incoming request; If there is a time difference against the system time (for each key) and the difference is more than 10 minutes, then it starts processing the request.

Now that we are bringing RabbitMQ into our solution, we need to revise this communication model as well. I was thinking to use a *delayed message exchange* for the 10 minutes time window, and then rewrite and reset the time (re-schedule for another 10 minutes) for duplicate messages incoming from service A.

Could share your ideas about this proposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after reading the documents I'm certain that such logic should be implemented in application layer (in my situation consumer software)

Comment: I agree, but maybe you can point how did you reach that conclusion